# How do I use the system PATH with Process.UseShellExecute=false?

Tags: c#, process, path

I am developing an application that spawns child processes using the `Process` API, with `UseShellExecute` set to `false`. The problem with this is that I don't want to go looking for the processes I'm spawning, since they are available in my system PATH. For example, I want to run Python scripts by just typing `SCRIPT_NAME.py ARGUMENTS`. However, when I set `Process.FileName` to be `SCRIPT_NAME.py`, I get an error telling me it couldn't find `SCRIPT_NAME.py`. I want the working directory to be where `SCRIPT_NAME.py` is, otherwise I'll have to specify the absolute path to `SCRIPT_NAME.py` and to its arguments, which is ridiculous and excessive.

I can avoid this by using `cmd.exe /C SCRIPT_NAME.py ARGUMENTS` but there are problems with force halting command prompt that are pushing me in this direction instead.

Comment: `UseShellExecute=false` basically translates into the requirement for a complete (relative or absolute) path.

Comment: Windows *always* searches through the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.  Regardless of UseShellExecute.  Not showing us what your PATH looks like makes it hard to help you.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you just need to search the set of available paths looking for the one that has python.exe.  Once you find that just fully qualify the python executable for launching in process

```
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
string pythonPath = null;
foreach (var p in path.Split(new char[] { ';' })) { 
  var fullPath = Path.Combine(p, "python.exe");
  if (File.Exists(fullPath)) { 
    pythonPath = fullPath;
    break;
  }
}

if (pythonPath != null) { 
  // Launch Process
} else { 
  throw new Exception("Couldn't find python on %PATH%");
}
```